# Users Order not Working

Tags: users, order

I'm trying to order my users with `craft.users.order('lastName')`, which should be no problem, since I'm pulling that straight from the documentation; however, it's not working for some reason. Is this a current a bug in Craft?

Currently, I have users with these last names: `Apple, Campbell, Jackson`.

With `order('lastName')`, it's printing out: `Campbell, Jackson, Apple`. So no alphabetical order is being applied `asc` or `desc`.

Answer (score 6):

Values in the documentation list possibilities, like: 'firstName' and 'lastName', which needs to be updated, since Craft only accepts lowercase values.

Changing 'firstName' to 'firstname' solves the issue.

Comment: Can you point to an example in the docs?

Comment: I too spent a lot of time attempting to order users by `lastName` and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. Fortunately, I found this post and changed the criteria to `{order:'lastname'}`, which worked. @BradBell The [user order docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.users#order) show the camelCase criteria values as working, but only the lowercase values seem to work in practice.

Comment: @AaronWaldon weird... the value of order gets passed directly into the SQL query that is generated and mapped back to the specified table columns. MySQL table columns are supposed to be [case insensitive](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html), so either should work.  Tested locally and it's that way for me.

Comment: I'm super grateful for this post. I just spent 90 minutes trying to debug my users being sorted arbitrarily, and trying (unsuccessfully) to find some way around it. This is still an issue in Craft 3.3. Thank you! 

Incidentally, I was debugging the raw MySQL query, and it wasn't sorting by `users.firstName`.... it was sorting by `content.field_firstName`—a field I happen to have but whose results in the query (after several joins) were all `NULL`.

Comment: Craft CMS 3.7.28 and the issue is still there.